# What's a concise word for "the expression inside a limit"? Limitand?

Tags: limits, terminology

In $\sqrt {f}$, $f$ is the radicand.

In $\sum g_i$, $g_2$ is a  summand.

In $x \times y \times z$, $y$ is a multiplicand.

In: $$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to +\infty} h_n(x)$$ or: $$h(x) \to \ell \quad \text {as} \quad x \to c$$

What's "$h$" called? The limitand?

Comment: "sequence" in the first, and "function" in the second.

Comment: That doesn't convey that I'm taking a limit of it, though.

Comment: I don't know of any word for that, in either danish (my native tongue) or english. I did understand what you meant when you used it in your answer to that $0^0$ question.

Comment: The function/sequence that we’re taking the limit of

Comment: "Summing" "Integrating"  "Multiplying" are all verbs with "ing" appended.  The "-and" suffix is a gerundive-ifier in Latin which changes the verb into an adjective (which in our usage becomes a noun.)   So "summand" is "something to be summed."   OTOH, "limit" and "derivative" are nouns, so they don't have gerundive forms.  You can try to coin "limitand" or "derivand" but people who know Latin will get upset, and you know how they can be.