# (Soft Question) Formal name for something one is taking the limit of

Tags: soft-question

When you are taking integral you have an integrand. When you are taking a sum you have a summand. Is there an analog of this for limits? How should one refer to $f(x)$ in the expression $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$?

Comment: Good question, and one that has been [asked before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028296/whats-a-concise-word-for-the-expression-inside-a-limit-limitand) without a good answer. I know of no such name. Want to start spreading "limitand"...?

Comment: Limitand it is!