# What is the term for the function whose limit is being taken?

Tags: integration, limits, terminology

Consider $\int x^2  dx$.  The *function being integrated* has a name, namely the *integrand*.

Is there a corresponding term for *the function whose limit is being taken*?

For example, if I have $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac {x^2 - 1}{x -1}$$ is there a term to say "The *function whose limit is being taken*, namely $\frac {x^2 - 1}{x -1}$, is equal to $x + 1$ when $x \neq 1$."

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028296/whats-a-concise-word-for-the-expression-inside-a-limit-limitand

Comment: I try to get students away from thinking about limits as an operation on functions (like the integral), and towards a relation between functions and values. In the first framework you have to deal with this nebulous "DNE" limit, while in the second you can just say it's not related to any particular value. Your question is still a good one though!

Comment: [Argument?](https://www.mathnstuff.com/math/spoken/here/2class/420/limit.htm#:~:text=Limit%20is%20a%20function.,-and&text=The%20argument%20is%20the%20thing,how%20to%20read%20limit%20notation.) Not standard, but at least one place where it's used.

Comment: The word "integrand" is useful because there are two functions under discussion: the integrand and the antiderivative (or bunch thereof, etc.). For a limit, there is typically only one function under discussion; so 90+% of the time (including in your example), you could simply say "the function".