# Is there a name for the operand of a limit operation?

Tags: calculus, limits, terminology

$$
f(x) \text{ is the “integrand" of} \int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x) \thinspace dx\\
\ \\
\ \\
f(x) \text { is the “_____" of }\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \\
$$

Is there a name for the operand of a limit operation?

Comment: This has been asked before [here (MSE Question 1028296)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028296/whats-a-concise-word-for-the-expression-inside-a-limit-limitand), however that has no accepted answer yet so this one cannot be marked as a duplicate. There is no widely-used term since there is little necessity for one.

Comment: This question many never get answered; so for now I'll think of "the operand of a limit operation" as being a "limand" rather than "limitand".